# Issue with Line Breaks and Blank Page After Updating PD4ML from Version 3 to 4

Tags: pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, pd4ml

I recently updated PD4ML from version 3 to version 4 in my project. After the update, I've noticed that the generated PDFs now have unexpected line breaks in each row of tables, and there's also an extra blank page added at the end of the PDFs.

I've tried to mitigate this issue by applying the default settings that were used in version 3, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!